# Tor Brower cannot play twitter and reddit videos/gif

Tags: tor, tor-browser-bundle

My Os is ubuntu 20.046LTS. Tor Brower(version 13.0 Security Level is standard) cannot play twitter and reddit videos/gif,but  can play the youtube videos.
The twitter videos post console shows the errors were  Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at data: (“media-src”) 、the Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at data:i (“object-src”).
The Reddit videos post console the error is "Google One Tap prompt was not displayed: suppressed_by_user"

i search for google, but it rarely have related answers.